# Average time to roll 1 on a die whose faces increase with each roll.

Tags: probability, average

**Context:**

Although I am comfortable with much of undergraduate-level math, probability is something I rarely venture into, bizarrely. Hence, I thought I'd come up with a recreational problem.

Suppose I have some $M(n)$ sided die, where $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is the number of rolls so far. That is, $M$ is dependent on $n$.

**Question:**

> Given $M(n)$, how do we calculate the average number of rolls it takes to roll a $1$?

**What I've got so far,**

I assume the information I'm looking for is extracted from the likelihood of halting after $n$ rolls. Clearly, the chance of rolling a $1$ on roll $k$ is $\frac{1}{M(k)}$. Thus, I believe the likelihood of halting after $n$ rolls is
$$1-\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{M(k)}\right),$$
unless I am mistaken. Where do I go from here? I assume some sort of summation is involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we get a 1 for the first time from the $n$th roll, we didn't get 1 from the previous $n-1$ rolls but we got it once from the $n$th roll. So the probability is:

$$\frac{1}{M(n)} \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \bigg(1-\frac{1}{M(k)}\bigg)$$

The expected number of rolls is the sum of the products of $n$ and the probability of halting at $n$. Thus the answer is:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Bigg( \frac{n}{M(n)} \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \bigg(1-\frac{1}{M(k)}\bigg)\Bigg)$$

Comment: I made a simple spreadsheet with $M(n)=n+1$ so we start with a coin and add one side per turn.  By the time the limit of the outer sum was up to $150$ the sum was about $4.6$.  The increments were decreasing very slowly, so I suspect it may diverge logarithmically or so.

Comment: If $M(n)=n+1$ then the expected number of rolls would be $\sum \frac{1}{n+1}$ which indeed diverges logarithmically! @RossMillikan

Comment: Such a simple argument.  I missed it.  Thanks.

Comment: @jjm336 Concise, intuitive, and informative. Much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to be of help :) @Graviton